# How to use Map or String as request or response type in spring boot while swagger ui can normally display their structure?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using spring boot and swagger 3, i find that when i use Map or String as my controller request or response type, the swagger UI can not display the structure normally, i have to create a DTO for every kind of request or response type, any workaround?

Comment: Can you please post your controller with annotations, and a screenshot showing what you mean by "Swagger UI can not display the structure normally"? What result do you expect to see in Swagger UI instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you can try this solution:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73019102/21301377)